# Display Link of Inserted Record Id in Toast in Salesforce LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforce-id, toast

I have a page which displays a toast message upon successfully inserting a custom object record. I think it would be appropriate to add the record id, so when I click on it, it will redirect to the standard record detail page. Upon testing, record is still inserting but id displayed on toast becomes **undefined**.

Here is the snippet of the function where I display the toast message:

```
createRecord() {

        saveCustomObject({
            newCustRecord: this.custRecord
        })
        .then(result => {
            
            this.custRecord = {};
            
            // This is where I display message
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success!!',
                message: 'Custom Object Record Created Successfully!!' + this.custRecord.Id,
                variant: 'success'
            }),);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
    }
```

Would appreciate if anyone could help me on this.

Comment: It does look like that the support for link has been introduced in LWC components. Check [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-show-toast-event/documentation) if that helps.

Comment: @JayantDas yeah, upon checking support for link has been provided. Followed the tutorial and finally implemented it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're deleting the record from memory `this.custRecord = {};` then trying to show it. This won't work. `this.custRecord = result;` should work, assuming `saveCustomObject` returns the newly created record.

Comment: Removed the unnecessary `this.custRecord = {};` and resolved the undefined id. For my major issue regarding the link for record detail page, I followed the documentation. Didn't know until now that it had been supported by Salesforce already. Thanks !